# Time dilation on the same medium

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Einstein's theory of special relativity says that time slows down or speeds up depending on how fast you move relative to something else.

Does that mean, that time dilation can occur within the same medium?

Example: A person moving for 10x speed of light for a few centuries VS a static person. Do they age differently? Both on earth/space/same medium. [Theoretical]

Comment: " _Example: A person moving for 10x speed of light for a few centuries_ " This is not possible even theoretically

Comment: @silverrahul ok um maybe speed of sound? like any speed basically I guess. Will there be dilation?

Comment: What do you mean by 'on the same medium'?

Comment: @MarcoOcram both in earth's atmosphere/in space, basically where atmosphere is the same for both situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the key points you should try to understand.

Time-dilation is an effect caused by motion- it is nothing to do with media.

The magnitude of the effect increases with relative speed. At the sorts of speeds at which we move relative to each other on Earth, the effects are so tiny we never notice them.

The effects are reciprocal. If you are moving through my stationary frame of reference, your clock will appear to run slow compared with clocks that are stationary relative to me. However, from your perspective, you will be stationary, and it will be I who appear to be moving, and it will be my clock that seems to be running slow compared with the clocks that are stationary relative to you.

To understand how we can both consider each other clocks to be moving slow, you must also take into account another effect known as the relativity of simultaneity. That effect means that if I synchronise all the clocks that are stationary relative to me, and you synchronise all the clocks that are stationary relative to you, we will each think the other's clocks seem out of synch with our own.

Time dilation and the relativity of simultaneity are analogous to effects we encounter when we compare different spatial reference frames. If you live in New York, say, and I live in London, we will each use a different reference frame to describe vertical and horizontal, owing to the fact that we live at different points on the curved surface of the Earth. If they were measured in my frame of reference, the heights of all the buildings in New York would appear to have shrunk, because they are leaning at an angle to my vertical. Likewise any horizontal planes in your New York frame of reference will appear tilted in my London frame of reference. The effect is entirely reciprocal. In your New York frame of reference, New York buildings are vertical whereas London buildings are tilted toward the horizontal and thus foreshortened in height.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. If one of the twins stays on Earth and another twin orbits the planet, they will find themselves younger when they arrive back.

Comment: Um, I mean there is an misunderstanding of my question. I understand that when A person is in different medium, time dilates and thus results in age difference, the twin paradox. But my question is what is both person are in the same medium, both in space, but one is not moving (in ISS for example) other is moving fast (travelling galaxies maybe) for an extended duration (few hundred/thousand/million years), do they age differently?

Comment: It has nothing to do with medium (whatever you understand by it). Time dilation in an inertial frame of reference is only a matter of body velocity. So if another twin stays on Earth or spends the time on ISS (moving with lesser speed than their galaxy-travelling sibling), it doesn't matter.

Comment: " _I understand that when A person is in different medium, time dilates and thus results in age difference, the twin paradox_ " Twin paradox and time dilation has got nothing to do with different mediums. Even if both are in vaccuum time dilation happens

Comment: So time dilation only depends on the speed of bodies, regardless of medium eh? Which brings me back to my initial question, so aging process is different if one is faster then the other for a long period of time right?